# Missing step in Evan's PDE?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In the attached proof, I am having trouble justifying the presence of "$x_n^{p-1}$" in eh line immediately below "Thus" and "Letting $m\to\infty$". I understand he uses Minkowski's inequality, and upgrades the $x_n$ inequality to a full gradient, but I can't figure out how to get that term.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Note that you need to estimate the term containing $\int_0^{x_n}$ twice, since you want to interchange order of integration. To this end you need Hölders inequality. Check the exponent $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$ and note that $x_n^{p-1}=(\int_0^{x_n} 1)^{p/q}$